# How to create a function that counts the number of twos in a list?

Tags: python, list, function

How can I create a function that counts the number of aggregated twos and returns a tuple?

Like this:

```
t=[2,2,3,3,3,4,3,4,2,2,2,2,2]     # in this example we have 2 twos, other numbers, and more 5 twos
counts_two(t)                   
# returns (2, 5)                               

t=[2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,4,2,2,4,5,2] # in this example we have 3 twos, other numbers, then 2 twos, followed by other numbers, and more 1 two
counts_two(t)
#returns (3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: `groupby` is a function that would probably be helpful for you

Comment: I think you're getting a lot of downvotes because you haven't really documented what you've tried. Perhaps if you demonstrated 1 or 2 things you've tried, you may get some helpful responses.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: `[sum(i==i for i in val) for key,val in groupyby(the_list) if key == 2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function `M` will count groups of a value. It outputs a list of group occurrences in this format: [index of group, length of group].

It uses a flag `m` to keep track of in/out of group. If it's out, it starts a new group occurrence, if it's in, it increments the group length. It goes down the list and tests equality of the value.

```
t=[2,2,3,3,3,4,3,4,2,2,2,2,2]
j=[2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,4,2,2,4,5,2]

def M(L, N):
    c = []
    m = 0
    for i,n in enumerate(L):
        if n == N:
            if m:
                c[-1][1] += 1
            else:
                c.append([i, 1])
            m = 1
        else:
            m = 0
    return c

print M(t, 2)
print M(j, 2)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 2], [8, 5]]
[[0, 3], [10, 2], [14, 1]]
```